# How to rejoin split words in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, join

So far on python I have made a file using the code:

```
text_file = open("Sentences_Positions.txt", "w")
text_file.write (str(positions))
text_file.write (str(ssplit))
text_file.close()
```

The code makes the file and writes individual words to it which I previously split, I need to find a way to open the file and join the split words then print it I have tried.

```
text_file = open("Sentences_Positions.txt", "r")
rejoin = ("Sentences_positions.txt").join('')
print (rejoin)
```

But all this does is print a blank line in the shell, how should I approach this and what other code could i try?

Comment: Is `ssplit` a list of strings?

Comment: The `str.join` method doesn't work like that. Please see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), and try this in the interactive interpreter: `print('-'.join('abc'))`. Also, your code makes no attempt to read the contents of `text_file`.

Comment: It's really hard to give you a proper answer from the information you've supplied so far. It would help if you answered my 1st comment. There are probably better ways to write that data to the file. You should put a small example of what the "Sentences_Positions.txt" file looks like into your question.

Comment: The variable ssplit is a list of words seperated by commas in a text file it looks like ['The', 'dog', 'is', 'black']. The code needs to effectively print 'The dog is black' I think but am not entirely sure, the join command seems to be the easiest way to do this

Comment: The `.join()` method is certainly useful, but you also need to deal with those quotes and commas. It would make this task a lot easier if you _didn't_ save the data using `text_file.write(str(ssplit))`. Instead, you could loop over the `ssplit` list, writing each string to a separate line. (You can also do that operation using the `.join` method). That way you wouldn't have the commas and quote marks to deal with. You _could_ just separate the words with a space, but putting them on separate lines makes the processing simpler.

Comment: How would I go about looping the ssplit list? I know that \n will make each word be saved on seperate lines but i wouldnt know how to incorporate that into a loop.

Comment: As I said, the simple way is to use `.join`, like this: `ssplit=['a', 'small', 'list', 'of', 'words']` `print('\n'.join(ssplit))`. So you can change your `text_file.write(str(ssplit))` to `text_file.write('\n'.join(ssplit) + '\n')`. The final `+ '\n'` puts a newline at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
rejoin = ("Sentences_positions.txt").join('')
```

with:

```
rejoin = ''.join(text_file.read().split(' '))
```

Also, you should probably not use `open` but rather the context manager:

```
with open("Sentences_Positions.txt") as text_file:
    rejoin = ''.join(text_file.read().split(' '))
    print (rejoin)
```

Otherwise the file remains open. Using the context manager, it will close it when it's done. (True for the first part of your code as well).

Comment: You are reading a string. what are you joining here, `rejoin = ''.join(text_file.read())`?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file content and join them by `''`

```
content = textfile.read().split(' ')
print ''.join(content)
```

Comment: _If_ `ssplit` is a list of strings, then the file will contain the string representation of that list. So we'll have quoted strings separated by commas, plus the brackets delimiting the list. It's probably a Good Idea to wait for the OP to give us some more details...

Comment: The OP has confirmed my suspicions. But maybe they can be convinced to write the data in a nicer way. ;)